# Doctrine GROUPBY with SELECT MAX

Tags: group-by, doctrine-orm, max, query-builder

Here is my table :

```
id | place |    date    |  valid
 1 |  ONE  | 10/12/2019 | true
 2 |  ONE  | 11/12/2019 | true
 3 |  ONE  | 12/12/2019 | true
 4 |  ONE  | 13/12/2019 | false
 5 |  ONE  | 14/12/2019 | false
 6 |  TWO  | 10/12/2019 | true
 7 |  TWO  | 11/12/2019 | true
 8 |  TWO  | 12/12/2019 | true
 9 |  TWO  | 13/12/2019 | true
10 |  TWO  | 14/12/2019 | false
11 |  OTH  | 10/12/2019 | true
12 |  OTH  | 11/12/2019 | true
13 |  OTH  | 12/12/2019 | true
14 |  OTH  | 13/12/2019 | true
15 |  OTH  | 14/12/2019 | true
```

I'm trying with doctrine and the QueryBuilder to get the id's of my table.
I need to get the id's of the MAX date by place where valid is equal to "true".
With the data's displayed, I want to get this result :

```
 3 |  ONE  | 12/12/2019 | true
 9 |  TWO  | 13/12/2019 | true
15 |  OTH  | 14/12/2019 | true
```

I tried some query builder but I can not get the results I wanted.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("o");
$qb->select('o.id, o.place');
$qb->addSelect($qb->expr()->max('o.date').' AS maxDate');
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('o.valid', true));
$qb->groupBy('o.place');
```

I also tried with a subquery but I have a problem to group the place, get the max date and return the ID 3 / 9 and 15.

How can I get the max date and group my lines by place please ?

Thanks

Comment: What does your current query return? It doesn't look too far off to me

Comment: The query return an array with all lines of the table separate in an array per line with field "place / id and maxdate".  The result isn't filtered by place or maxDate